# Python: How to find coordinates of short sequences in a FASTA file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I have a list of short sequences that I want to obtain its coordinate or in another word to get its bed file after compare with a fasta file which contains original sequences.

Fasta file:

```
>PGH2
CGTAGCGGCTGAGTGCGCGGATAGCGCGTA
```

Short sequence fasta file:

```
>PGH2
CGGCTGAGT
```

Is there any ways to obtain its coordinate? Bedtools can't help much.

Desired output:

```
PGH2  6 14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `BioPyton`

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for long_sequence_record in SeqIO.parse(open('long_sequences.fasta'), 'fasta'):
    long_sequence = str(long_sequence_record.seq)

    for short_sequence_record in SeqIO.parse(open('short_sequences.fasta'), 'fasta'):
        short_sequence = str(short_sequence_record.seq)

        if short_sequence in long_sequence:
            start = long_sequence.index(short_sequence) + 1
            stop = start + len(short_sequence) - 1
            print short_sequence_record.id, start, stop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "CGTAGCGGCTGAGTGCGCGGATAGCGCGTA"
str2 = "CGGCTGAGT"
index = str1.index(str2)
print index
```

output: index = 5, to get 6,14 use index+1, index+len(str2)

Comment: Thanks. For your information str1 and str2 are from two different files which is fasta file with sequence id.